# How to capture JSON result from Azure CLI within NodeJS script

Tags: json, node.js, azure, command-line-interface, capture

Is there a way to capture the JSON objects from the Azure NodeJS CLI from within a NodeJS script? I could do something like exec( 'azure vm list' ) and write a promise to process the deferred stdout result, or I could hijack the process.stream.write method, but looking at the CLI code, which is quite extensive, I thought there might be a way to pass a callback to the cli function or some other option that might directly return the JSON result. I see you are using the winston logger module -- I might be familiar with this, but perhaps there is a hook there that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

azure vm list does have a --json option:

```
 C:\>azure vm list -h
 help:    List Azure VMs
 help:
 help:    Usage: vm list [options]
 help:
 help:    Options:
 help:      -h, --help               output usage information
 help:      -s, --subscription <id>  use the subscription id
 help:      -d, --dns-name <name>    only show VMs for this DNS name
 help:      -v, --verbose            use verbose output
 help:      --json                   use json output
```

You can get the json result in the callback of an exec(...) call.  Would this work for your?

Comment: Maggie 

Thank you for yor response.  I am aware that I "can get the json result in the callback of an exec(...) call."  I just thought there might be a more convienient method using an argument to the cli module itself saving the hassle of making the result of the callback available for modification and resubmission.  And there are so many modules used in the cli, e.g. a "winston logger" which is probably also capturing command results, I suspect there is a hook that the developers know about.  

But again, thanks anyway. 

Robin

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, check this gist: https://gist.github.com/4415326 and you'll see how without doing exec. You basically override the logger hanging off the CLI.

As a side note I am about to publish a new module, azure-cli-buddy that will make it easy to call the CLI using this technique and to receive results in JSON.

Comment: Glenn did you eventually publish the module? Is this it https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-scripty ?

Comment: Yup that is it. Though the CLI also supports --json which scripty builds around.